# Can I open a "backup" bank account?

Tags: uplink

I'd like to open up an offshore bank account and have some money in it so that when I get caught, I can quickly get up to speed when I create a new agent.

Is this possible?

Comment: Every time I see these I can't help second guessing the content... This is for a video game... *Is it though..?* Yes... Yes it is...... *Is it though...?*

Comment: You know I have no idea. It should work in theory. Try it?

Comment: @Resonating I tried doing it one way, but it didn't work, so I'm wondering if there's another way. Should I just answer my own question with a "no" and what I've tried?

Comment: Absolutely. That's why you can answer your own questions. What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no (documented) way of doing this.

All company information, including IP addresses, are randomly generated on a per-agent basis. This means that you cannot create a bank account on one save file and access it on another. Even if you tried, the credentials wouldn't work on the other save file.

Comment: Aha, so the world isn't persistent. Okay.

Comment: @Resonating I wish it was, to be honest..

Answer (score 2):

No, the save files in Uplink are completely independant of each other. If you get caught, all your accounts are frozen and the game ends.

Comment: Would be neat if you could drop it in someone else's account.  Like another (idle) agent you create?